# Apache Ant: Run 2 java programs from same build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I want to run 2 similar java programs using one (the same) ant file.

I have the follwing build.xml

```
<project name ="Project" basedir="." default="main">


<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="main-class" value="implementation1.Main"/>


<target name="main" depends="clean,zip"/>

<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete file ="${zipname}"/>
</target>


<target name = "compile">
    <mkdir dir = "${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="." destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>


<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
    </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>


<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true" spawn="true" >
    </java>
</target>
```

In the directory, where my build.xml is located, I have an "src" folder. 
In the path ./src/implementation1/
I have the .java file for my project and a seperate main file in the folder implementation1. It works when I run ant in my folder.

However, I have another (alternative) implementation of my project, let it be called projectAlt.java and it is stored in the folder ./src/implementation2.

Problem 1: When I run the ant with the folder implementation2 in src, I get lots of errors. If I remove the folder, the ant works normally.

Problem 2: How would I set things up in a way that first implementation1 is run then implementation2 ?

I have made myself somewhat clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually you should avoid relative path in ant because it uses current directory and you will get in trouble with that

Comment: The assignment i'm working for, however, requires me to put both implementations in the same src file and use different package paths. How do I go about this?

Comment: @Spara That is true in Java code, but it’s not true in Ant.  Ant always resolves relative paths against the project’s basedir.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I
resorted to making similar package structures in eclipse, jar now makes 2 jars each with
2 different main classes that are each run by a respective run call.